# How to recover connection between Google account and Google Scholar alerts after creating a gmail address for the account?

Tags: google-account, google-scholar, bug-trackers

### Context

I used a Google account for years with a non-google email address as primary email and created many Google Scholar alerts. After accepting Google's offer in 2022 to create a gmail address for my Google account and deleting the old primary email address from my account, Google Scholar continues sending alerts to the old email address and stopped listing my alerts under "Alerts" in Google Scholar. There, it now says "Alerts for xyz@gmail.com" where xyz is my new gmail. So I guess Google Scholar's alert database table uses the email address as a key, rather than a permanent account identifier.

### The specific problems

1. How can I get my existing alerts back into the account?
2. How can I tell Google to stop sending alerts to my old email
   address?
3. Is there a better way to re-populate my account with my alerts than
   going through my archived emails and creating each alert manually
   again?

### Things I tried but did not work

- Re-adding my old email address as an alternative contact in my account, hoping this would re-establish the connection to my alerts: The list of alerts is still empty.
- Creating a new Google account using the old email address, choosing "Use your existing email - Enter the email address you want to use for your Google Account": Google rejects the email address with "That username is taken. Try another." This suggests that Google still has the old email address on record as taken for an account.
- Account recovery using the old email address: On sign-in page, clicked "Forgot password?", received and entered recovery code, landed on the "Welcome" page for one of my other Google accounts (instead of asking for a new password to be set) and received an email "Your Google Account was recovered successfully" quoting the "xyz@gmail.com" email.

### Notes

Another way of looking at this is that I found a bug in the Google account system and need to find out how to report the bug to Google and get it fixed so that I can regain full control of my Google Scholar alert settings.

Moved from https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/189126/how-to-recover-connection-between-google-account-and-google-scholar-alerts-after

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Added heading "The specific problems" before the list of problems to make this more clear.